# How to hide rsync output for existing and synced files?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have the output:

```
sent 66 bytes  received 12 bytes  156.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.62
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list

sent 66 bytes  received 12 bytes  156.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.62
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 12 bytes  158.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 2.58
sending incremental file list
mysql-bin.000118
            204 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 229 bytes  received 35 bytes  528.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 0.77
```

Is there a way to show only:

```
sending incremental file list
mysql-bin.000118
            204 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 229 bytes  received 35 bytes  528.00 bytes/sec
total size is 204  speedup is 0.77
```

Which is the only missing file.

Edit: Thanks BowlOfRed, I was using:

```
rsync -azvp --progress --ignore-existing
```

Now I am using as in the answer and it's working.

```
rsync -azp --info=name,progress --ignore-existing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention how you're invoking rsync or what version you're using.   This looks like you're using `-P`, which sets things similar to `-v` in providing both the incremental list progress as well as the stats at the end.

I don't know a way to provide the "sending incremental" and ending stats only for covered transfers, but you could remove them both and give only the progress/incremental so that the output is silent when no files are transferred.   With rsync 3.x, this is best done by replacing `-P` with more fine-grained invocations of `--info`.

Example with rsync 3.2.7:

```
$ rsync -a --info=name,progress dir/ dir2
$ touch dir/a
$ rsync -a --info=name,progress dir/ dir2
a
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=2/4)
$
```